# TabLayout скролится в неверную позицию после вызова notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: java, android

Вот [оригинал вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056039/tablayout-scrolls-to-unkown-position-after-calling-notifydatasetchanged-on-pager) у меня такая же проблема. Могу только добавить, что проблема начинается если вкладок больше 12, если 12 или меньше всё работает без проблем.

Ситуация такая - выбираем любую вкладку, получаем нужную нам информацию, вызываем `pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` текущая выделенная вкладка `TabLayout` скролится в рандомное место, а текущий фрагмент остаётся на месте, как и должен быть. В моём случае `pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` используется для обновления преставления на фрагменте.
Просьба помочь разобраться. Этот же вопрос на сайте [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=267098)

([image])

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    final SampleFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: а вопросе по ссылке есть решение​. оно вам не подходит?

Comment: Нет и оно не работает на его же коде.

Comment: Тут баг скорей не в TabLayout, а где-то глубже.
Там если пройтись дебагом, то можно найти метод `calculateScrollXForTab`, который и высчитывает, куда проскролить TabLayout. И вот `selectedChild.getLeft()` возвращает вообще странные числа. Из-за этого числа скролл и скачет. Но это только описание проблемы, как это исправить - что-то пока не придумал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте после каждого вызова у `PagerAdapter` метода `notifyDataSetChanged()` перевыбирать `Tab`, например в данном случае так:

```
...
findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(
                        tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()
                );
                if (tab != null) {
                    tab.select();
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
...
```

побочный эффект такого подхода - анимация.

Еще можно попробовать такой вариант:

```
...
findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setScrollPosition(
                        tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition(), 0, true
                );
            }
        })
    }
});
...
```

В теории он должен сработать без анимации.

Можно привязывать ViewPager к TabLayout без автообновления, но тогда, скорее всего, придётся самостоятельно обновлять позиции `Tab`-ов у `TabLayout`, но зато именно в те моменты, когда Вам действительно этого хочется:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, false);
```

Comment: спасибо, но не помогло, проверил и у себя и на оригинальном коде

Comment: все табы рабочие, проблема начинается, когда табов больше 12

Comment: вот тут код оригинала [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4OuWqnzFA1yeTREdDVDdVFRNzA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: ну что могу сказать - работает.... но есть проблема эстетическая, появилась анимация прокрутки вкладки до текущей с самого начала... чего быть не должно

Comment: второй вариант не работает

Comment: Обновил ответ. Второй вариант в теории должен помочь лучше, но всегда остается более хардкодный, когда Вы сможете контролировать всё :)